# AWS AppSync Mutation not Updating Data - What Could be the Issue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, graphql, apollo-client, aws-appsync

I'm using AWS AppSync to query and create data but now I need to update the objects. I'm using the udpate mutation created by AppSync but it is returning the data without updating. Could you please look into it? It's important!

```
mutation MyMutation($id: ID = "2023439223", $currency: String = "", $assignedTo: String = "", $amount: String = "") {
  updateZeeepyOrders(input: {amount: $amount, assignedTo: $assignedTo, currency: $currency, id: $id}) {
    id
    amount
    langFrom
  }
}
```

Here I'm getting the data without being modified-

```
{
  "data": {
    "updateZeeepyOrders": {
      "id": "2023439223",
      "amount": "0",
      "langFrom": "hindi"
    }
  }
}
```

Same thing I'm getting when tried on Postman. Could you please suggest what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add the latest **_version** of your object inside input like this -

```
mutation MyMutation($id: ID = "2023439223", $currency: String = "", $assignedTo: String = "", $amount: String = "") {
  updateZeeepyOrders(input: {_version:21, amount: $amount, assignedTo: $assignedTo, currency: $currency, id: $id}) {
    id
    amount
    langFrom
  }
}
```

You'll find the object version in your DynamoDB Table.

I found the solution in one of the github discussions- https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/3237#issuecomment-619359322

Comment: The solution worked. Can't believe such small issue could cause such big problem. Thanks for the solution.